# NuGet.targets error : '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character after upgrade to .Net Core 2.1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

after upgrade to .Net Core 2.1.1 I got this error:

```
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.301\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : An error 
occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'System.IO.4.3.0' from source
     'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'. 
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.301\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   '.', 
hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
```

not able to solve it using

```
nuget.exe locals -clear global-packages
nuget.exe locals -clear packages-cache
nuget.exe locals -clear http-cache
```

or

```
nuget.exe locals -clear all
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Please share the project file that leads to this error (or create a new one as a minimal sample)

Comment: I've reinstalled all my system and the problem seems gone

Comment: I'm getting this after updating VS and getting dotnet core sdk 2.1.302

Comment: From what I am reading it seems you were on the right track but instead of deleting the whole solution you can just delete the packages folder -> get nuget command line -> run commands listed above and then restore nuget packages

Answer (score 21):

In my case it was simple, I just did the following:

- In Visual Studio, click: TOOLS > NUGET PACKAGE MANAGER > PACKAGE MANAGER SETTINGS
- Select Option NUGET PACKAGE MANAGER > GENERAL
- In General, click on button CLEAR ALL NUGET CACHE(S) await a few seconds
- After this , close all windows and go to TOOLS > NUGET PACKAGE MANAGER > PACKAGE MANAGER **CONSOLE**
- type *dotnet restore*
- done =)

Comment: Thank you! Was tearing my hair out for the past two hours with this.....

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution. Delete the file AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config and then run the visual studio it can create the new file of NuGet.config

Answer (score 0):

So I had this issue when ever I used to clone a new repo and my IDE tried to restore the nuget packages first, it would refuse to work without nuget cache being cleard. The below steps helped me fix this after some "investigation".

1. Delete the nuget config file from (C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet)
2. In my case the issue was with internal nuget URL. There was some issue with VS IDE unable to communicate with the internal nuget store which had changed from http to https. [image]
3. Close all instances of VS 2019 and try again.

Once the new internal nuget source was replaced with new url, the issue seemed to have been fixed.

I am running VS 2019 v 16.10.4 @Win 10

Answer (score 0):

I've tried pretty much everything:

- Deleted `/obj` and `/bin` folders
- Cleared NuGet cache
- Updated Visual Studio to latest version
- Restarted PC
- Created a new project and verified that builds, however when adding additional NuGet packages and tried to restore them, got the same issue
- Tried some other stuff that I don't recall, however it didn't help

What actually resolved this issue for me was to delete the `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NugetFallbackFolder\` and then run `dotnet restore` in any of my projects that were failing to build (all of them, which were using NuGet) and then subsequent `dotnet build` worked ok!

It seems like that folder should be safe to delete ([Could I remove or move the folder NuGetFallbackFolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494086/could-i-remove-or-move-the-folder-nugetfallbackfolder#51499971)), however I got a few errors after this with package manager, etc, which I worked around by re-creating an empty `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NugetFallbackFolder\` and it all worked fine after that.

Hope this helps somebody in the same situation! :)