# Could I remove or move the folder NuGetFallbackFolder?

Tags: .net-core

Could I remove the folder `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\` or move it to other folder? *(better not in disk C)*

If could remove, how to remove? delete the folder directly? any side effects or damages?

If could move, how to move? target folder like `D:\NuGetFallbackFolder`? How can I do it?

Comment: I removed all versions of .net core sdk, and then remove the folder "NuGetFallbackFolder", and installed again only the latest version. the folder reduce from about 3GB to 1GB current. Seems no any side effect, and my programs still working properly after recompile ^_^

Answer (score 20):

This folder contains a set of Nuget packages that the SDK expects to use. It's used as a nuget source whenever `dotnet` is trying to resolve nuget packages. Removing is generally similar to removing your nuget cache: .NET Core will simply not find the packages and download them into the (normal, non-NuGetFallbackFolder) local nuget cache.

Some distributions of .NET Core do not contain the `NuGetFallbackFolder`. The only consequence is that `dotnet` will download all those packages as soon as it needs them (possibly on the first SDK command).

If you move it around, .NET Core won't know about the new location and just treat it as if you had deleted the directory. On Linux, I would use a symlink to point from the old location to the new one. I don't know if Windows supports that.

Comment: xp and lower, cmd -> junction; 7 and above, cmd -> mklink

Comment: This is what i've got after deleting it:

`The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.  NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'`

Comment: You can delete the content, not the folder iself. As according to the [specification](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-Fallback-package-folders): "All fallback package folders specified must exist"

Answer (score 1):

after searching the internet and trying some in vain:
deleting the NuGetFallbackFolder in the corresponding .NET SDK and
repairing in Windows Uninstall Programm helps really
in my case it worked : the build process in solution got all new in