# Error on Build: JsonException: '0x00' is an invalid start of a value

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Using .NET FW 6 with VS 2022. When I try to build my project I'm getting this error....

```
JsonException: '0x00' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.StaticWebAssetsManifest.FromJsonBytes(Byte[] jsonBytes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest.PersistManifest(StaticWebAssetsManifest manifest)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest.Execute()
JsonReaderException: '0x00' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
    Website C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets    411
```

Line 411 of the file Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets is the top line of this....

```
    <GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest
  Source="$(PackageId)"
  BasePath="$(StaticWebAssetBasePath)"
  Mode="$(StaticWebAssetProjectMode)"
  ManifestType="Build"
  ReferencedProjectsConfigurations="@(StaticWebAssetProjectConfiguration)"
  DiscoveryPatterns="@(StaticWebAssetDiscoveryPattern)"
  Assets="@(StaticWebAsset)"
  ManifestPath="$(StaticWebAssetBuildManifestPath)">
  </GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest>
```

I tried reinstalling VS, the latest stable .NET 6 FW, tried clelaring the nuget cache and doing a 'dotnet restore', per this... [NuGet.targets error : '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character after upgrade to .Net Core 2.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998655/nuget-targets-error-hexadecimal-value-0x00-is-an-invalid-character-after)

Also I searched diligently online but could not find an answer. Do you have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an empty json file somewhere

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same error message but my problem was caused by a corrupted

> obj\Debug\net6.0\staticwebassets.build.json

in one of the project folders. I had to manually delete the obj folder. "Clean Solution" in Visual Studio did not solve the problem.

Comment: In migrating from .NET 4 to .NET 6, I've found it very useful to add a script to the top project folder that allows me to quickly remove all bin and obj files. It is a new member to the 'Developing on Windows' toolbox. I'm now leaning towards the rule: "for any strange compile error, first run script," It's disconcerting how often this works.

Comment: I deleted my bin and object and it works

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I had to reinstall GIT. This time I selected the option "Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style line endings" and it worked! Windows must've been doing some conversion with the LF and it was messing up the build. Hope this helps others!

Comment: JFYI usually you don't need to reinstall git to change this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I get rid of this error installing "Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Razor" package using NuGet Package.

Follow below steps:

Right click on project -> select "Manage NuGet Packages" -> go to Browse tab -> in search bar type "Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Razor" -> click install latest or as per your required version -> and build/rebuild the solution.

hopefully it will work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .NET 8 but I guess this issue is just some corrupted file. I had to clone my repo again and manually transfer my changes from this `corrupted source` to my new local repo. The problem is to find which file is corrupted... That's why I've cloned again. But it solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually Deleted the obj folder
2. Clean Solution
3. Rebuild

It solved the issue for me. Please try.